# Fresh project fail to compile after installing vuetify in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a problem in vue.js, i have created a new project using webstorm and it runs with no problem at all and i can see vue logo.
in next step i want to install vuetify but i get errors as below list:

> > Failed to compile.
> >
> > ./src/plugins/vuetify.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> >     'vuetify/lib' in 'PATH TO MY PROJECT'
> >
> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
> >      ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
> >     TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
> >         at VuetifyLoaderPlugin.apply (/home/tina/WebstormProjects/tinalasttry/node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/plugin.js:28:29)
> >         at webpack (/home/tina/WebstormProjects/tinalasttry/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:51:13)
> >         at serve (/home/tina/WebstormProjects/tinalasttry/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:161:22)
> >         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

i have installed vuetify using command add vuetify and also i tried installing it from vue ui.
i have installed vuetify before with no problem and i checked for any version changes or updates but they are all same but now cant install in a fresh and new project.

```
 vuetify.js

    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

    Vue.use(Vuetify);

    export default new Vuetify({
    });
```

Comment: try `npm i` agian and build again

Comment: i have tried it unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: what `command` yo, vue, npm, yarn, bower, bash ? you are running vue 4.*? how did you setup vue? vue cli, vue ui, webstorm template, webpack? did you follow https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#quick-start?

Comment: What version of Vuetify Loader are you running? Version 1.4.0 was released 6 hours ago, which may just be coincidence or you might have got unlucky...

Comment: i use npm and i setup vue from webstorm templates for adding vuetify i used add vue add vuetify and i also tried adding vuetify from vue ui but same errors

Comment: Ahh typescript - all good

Comment: i have updated my post with adding my vuetify.js codes

Comment: i am using vuetify version 2.1.11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Edit plugins.js to fix the issue (temporary)

```js
  constructor (options) {
    this.options = (options) ? options : {}
  }
```

Source: 
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/pull/97#issuecomment-557767269

Comment: where is plugins.js i got  vuetify.js in plugins directory

Comment: Its in `node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/plugin.js`. You need to update this right now, but it was fixed in `vuetify-loader` already. Only need to wait for an update of the package.

Comment: See on error log, in your case, must be in `/home/tina/WebstormProjects/tinalasttry/node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/plugin.js`

Comment: Kudos (wish I had more votes)  now I'm smarter "npm-wise"
I just append an OR Object
-- this.options = options
++ this.options = options || {}

Answer (score 0):

the issue because dependency was not found. do following and reload the project will fix the issue

```
npm install --save vuetify/lib/framework
```