# Failed to compile. ./src/main.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.plugins/vuetify' in 'C:\vue\testvueapp\src'

Tags: vue.js

I have this error `Failed to compile.  ./src/main.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.plugins/vuetify' in 'C:\vue\testvueapp\src'` but I have installed it [image]

and this is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import vuetify from '.plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
 vuetify,
 render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like path issue. tryout below

```
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
```

Comment: what alias is referring to?

Comment: @ is a alias for src directory. checkout in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/10733865

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
```

Notice the slightest of path difference before plugins here

Comment: what if it is in node_modules folder?

Comment: Generally, it would also have been declared inside the plugins folder in vuetify.js file. It's a better approach as there you can also change the theme colors if you'll like to.
Inside the vuetify.js file, you can do 

import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';

Answer (score 1):

the issue because dependency was not found. do following and reload the project will fix the issue

```
npm install --save vuetify/lib/framework
```

[Solved Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005933/fresh-project-fail-to-compile-after-installing-vuetify-in-vue-js/65779149#65779149)